# Filter out old questions?

Tags: support, questions, old-questions, filtering

I was just looking for whether StackOverflow can be localized somehow or what the current state of development is regarding this topic. But it is difficult to find anything because I get lots of old questions, which are now not interesting.

I've encountered the same thing sometimes on SO: you search for something (e.g. JavaScript) and find a lot of things that are already outdated.

So how can I filter out such questions?

Comment: Just realized you don't mean "old" but rather "deprecated" - something can be deprecated  after a week. Found a dupe. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Interesting: Upvote questions as, yes, deprecated. That would be a nice system. Better than some time based filtering. Thank you for the link ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [help-centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) you can use created: and lastactive: to specify a date range.

> year only – e.g., created:2012..2013 searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2013; created:2012 searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2012.

or relative like so

> if you want to see all the posts active in the last three months, use lastactive:3m..

and add your desired search terms to that to get what you want.

Comment: Awkward... didn't know about the lot of options! You live and lern. I mainly used stupid Google to find things on SO...